# Bufferedreader and InputStreamReader

Tags: bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I am having trouble getting my java program to read any text files.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        try {
            long base = Long.parseLong(args[0]);

            String input = br.readLine(); //read first line till the end of file

            long list = Long.parseLong(input);

            convertBase(base, list);
        }
        finally {
            br.close();
        }
}
```

The program works when I manually type the values into the command line, but when I try to use a text file it throws exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "baseconverion.txt"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at FromDecimal.main(FromDecimal.java:46)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong/missing.

Comment: You should print `input` before trying to process it - you might be surprised about its content.

Comment: You are trying to parse a filename as a `long`. Solution: don't. NB `readLine()` doesn't 'read first line till the end of file'. Why are you trying to parse a text file as `longs` in the first place?

Comment: I need to parse to longs because I have another method where I convert decimal number to base

Comment: Parsing to longs converts to *binary*, not decimal, but you don't have any requirement to parse the *filename* as a long. You have your inputs and arguments mixed up somehow. NB There is exactly nothing here that reads a text file.

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to use a text file

You mean 'when I enter a filename instead of a number'. You aren't 'try[ing]' to use a text file' at all. All you're doing is entering a filename at the console. There is nothing here that opens or reads a text file whatsoever. Java is not magic: it won't magically realize that's a filename and magically open it for you.

You need to read about file I/O in the Java Tutorial and the Javadoc.

You also shouldn't be using `Long.parseLong()` if your objective is to convert decimal into another base. You need to pass the original line to your conversion method.